# Dataframe from vector values

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, indexing

I have vectors such as

```
porcentages1<-c(19.63081,29.87414,32.12955,18.36550)
porcentages2<-c(19.58452,29.94807,32.19970,18.26772)
```

Where each index of the vector represents a percentage of an item (for example the first index represents the percentage of dogs and the second the percentage of cats)

I want to create a data frame such as
[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSFGo.png)

Any ideas on how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

as_tibble(rbind(porcentages1, porcentages2)) %>% 
  rename(Dogs = V1, Cats = V2, Sharks = V3, Turtles = V4)
```

```
  Dogs  Cats Sharks Turtles
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1  19.6  29.9   32.1    18.4
2  19.6  29.9   32.2    18.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

output <- setnames(as.data.table(transpose(list(porcentages1, porcentages2))),
                   c("Dogs", "Cats", "Sharks", "Turtles"))
```

**Output**

output

```
       Dogs     Cats   Sharks  Turtles
1: 19.63081 29.87414 32.12955 18.36550
2: 19.58452 29.94807 32.19970 18.26772
```

Or another option using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

map_dfc(purrr::transpose(list(porcentages1, porcentages2)), ~ unlist(tibble(.))) %>%
  set_names(c("Dogs", "Cats", "Sharks", "Turtles"))
```